# How do I access itextsharp methods using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, itext

I have not been programming for a while and am used to com interface. I understand that itextsharp uses 100% managed code.
How do I access itextsharp 5.5.9 methods using vbscript?

Answer (score 1):

You don't. VBScript can't use .Net classes unless they expose a COM object. Either switch to PowerShell or find a PDF component with a COM interface.